# Facebook authentication button fails to load in Chromium browser spawned by Apify PuppeteerCrawler

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, web-crawler, puppeteer, apify

**Background**

I am trying to scrape some content from [prycd.com](https://www.prycd.com). But before that, I need to login into my prycd.com account, and then only I can access that page. For the same, I have used Apify with Puppeteer Crawler to automate the task.

**Environment**

1. node (v14.17.4)
2. apify-cli (v0.6.2)

Please note that my local machine is a Macbook but the same issue is seen when running in Apify cloud as well.

**Issue**

After I run the apify actor using the command `apify run -p` in my local machine, the puppeteer tries to load the URL (https://www.prycd.com/comp-report) which I had provided in the start URLs. For this URL to load the user needs to log in so a login overlay is open in the browser. This login overlay has 3 options for authentication: google authentication, Facebook authentication, and native authentication.

[Login Screen of prycd.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYZ77.png)

However, when I run apify actor to load this page then the Facebook authentication button fails to load and throws the error in the console shown below image. I only require native login for my task, but since the Facebook authentication button fails to load I am unable to operate the native login as well. I tried googling to see if others also has faced a similar issue but couldn't find anything.

[Error seen in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWTMu.png)

**Approaches Tried**

I have tried various approaches I am familiar with to fix this issue but none seem to work. These are some operations I tried:

1. Anti-scraping methods (Browser fingerprinting, checked presence of tracker, etc)
2. Directly calling the login API to obtain the session token.
3. Tried disabling loading of social authentication button (wasn't successful in doing this)
4. Played around with request headers and CORS.

**Sample code snippet**

```
/* eslint-disable indent */
const Apify = require('apify');

const { utils: { log, puppeteer } } = Apify;

Apify.main(async () => {
  const { startUrls, email, password } = await Apify.getInput();

  const requestList = await Apify.openRequestList('start-urls', startUrls);
  const handlePageTimeoutSecs = 180; // 3 minutes;
  // const proxyConfiguration = await Apify.createProxyConfiguration();

  const width = 1280;
  const height = 800;

  const crawler = new Apify.PuppeteerCrawler({
    requestList,
    handlePageTimeoutSecs,
    // proxyConfiguration,
    useSessionPool: true,
    persistCookiesPerSession: true,
    launchContext: {
      useChrome: true,
      stealth: true,
      userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Safari/537.36',
      launchOptions: {
        args: [
          `--window-size=${width},${height}`,
        ],
      },
    },
    preNavigationHooks: [
      async (crawlingContext) => {
        const { page, request } = crawlingContext;

        const blockedUrlPatterns = [
          '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.svg', '.gif', '.webp', '.webm', '.ico', '.woff', '.eot',
          '.tff', '.woff2',
        ];

        await puppeteer.blockRequests(page, {
          urlPatterns: blockedUrlPatterns,
          extraUrlPatterns: [],
        });
      },
    ],
    handlePageFunction: async (context) => {
      const { request: { url }, page } = context;
      log.info('Processing:', { url });

      // Wait for LOG IN form to show up
      await page.waitForSelector('#switchToEmailLink_SM_ROOT_COMP1', {
        visible: true,
        timeout: 10000,
      });

      await Promise.all([
        page.click('#switchToEmailLink_SM_ROOT_COMP1', { delay: 100 }),
      ]);

      log.info('Signing in to prycd.com');

      // Fill in email and password
      await page.evaluate((a, b) => {
        document.querySelector('#input_input_emailInput_SM_ROOT_COMP1').value = a;
        document.querySelector('#input_input_passwordInput_SM_ROOT_COMP1').value = b;
      }, email, password);

      // Click LOG IN button
      await Promise.all([
        page.click('div#okButton_SM_ROOT_COMP1 > button', { delay: 100 }),
        page.waitForNavigation(),
      ]);
    },
    handleFailedRequestFunction: async ({ request }) => {
      log.warning(`Request ${request.url} failed too many times`);
    },
    postNavigationHooks: [
      async (crawlingContext) => {
        const { request, response, session } = crawlingContext;
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
        if (session.retireOnBlockedStatusCodes(response._status)) {
          log.error(`Page didn't load for ${request.url}`);
        }
      },
    ],
  });

  log.info('Starting the crawl.');
  await crawler.run();
  log.info('Crawl finished.');
});
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried removing the `puppeteer.blockRequests`? maybe some beacon gif that might be necessary for the page to function. also you don't seem to be using `headless: false`. try not to hardcode your user-agent unless really necessary

Comment: @pocesar, I tried both i.e. removing the `blockRequests` from the `preNavigationHooks` and also passed `headless: false` but both didn't work. Also, the reason I hardcoded `user-agent` was to try if this was an issue with the browser fingerprinting but before that I hadn't used it but still didn't work on both cases.